# Paste current time using global hotkey in C#

Tags: c#, clipboard, sendkeys

I am trying to paste current time in any windows using C#. So I defined a global hotkey in C# and when I press the hotkey in any windows, the current time is pasted there.

The issue is that it works perfectly with Notepad, but in Notepad++ it pastes the current time just once and then after that it pastes some strange character which is shown by SYN in Notepad++. I added a thread.sleep(500); before paste command and it works in every windows.

So the question is that why without delay it works in Notepad and not in Notepad++? and how I can get rid of the sleep delay in order to make it works in every windows?

Thanks in advance.

here is my code:

```
    public static void PasteDT()
    {
        ClipPut(DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss"));
        //Thread.Sleep(500); //<< without this line it works just once in Notepad++
        SendKeys.SendWait("^v");
    }

    public static void ClipPut(string ClipboardText)
    {
        Thread clipboardThread = new Thread(() => Clipboard.SetText(ClipboardText));
        clipboardThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        clipboardThread.IsBackground = false;
        clipboardThread.Start();
        clipboardThread.Join();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the `SendKeys.Send` is processed by `Notepad++` when the hotkey is pressed. If the hotkey already has a function in `Notepad++`, or it conflicts then you get undefined behaviour.

The reason why the sleep is working is because it gives you time to release the initial triggering hotkey, and then `Notepad++` processes the paste command correctly.

I don't believe there is a way to resolve this using `SendKeys`, you can however use `SendInput`, which gets queued by the application and processed on the "hotkey up".

In the past, when I've had to send keys to applications I have used [Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/), which internally wraps the low level Win32 `SendInput` calls. The resultant code in your case would be:

```
//...
Thread clipboardThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    Clipboard.SetText(ClipboardText);
});
clipboardThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
clipboardThread.IsBackground = false;
clipboardThread.Start();
clipboardThread.Join();

InputSimulator.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_V);
//...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I rather not to use any dll for such task. There is really no solution using C# itself and without using any third-party dll?

Comment: There is an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761169/send-keys-through-sendinput-in-user32-dll) of how to interface directly with `SendInput` without a third party DLL. It will work in the same way as the code in my answer, but you will have to handle key presses on a more granular level