# Installed InputSimulator via NuGet, no members accessible

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

In Visual Studio 2013, I installed a C# package called "[InputSimulator](https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/)."  After doing so, I see a new reference get added to my project called "WindowsInput."  (i.e., WindowsInput.dll)

The problem is that none of the methods that the codeplex site talks about are accessible.  If I try:

```
InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry("Say hello!");
```

I get the error:

```
Error   14  'WindowsInput.InputSimulator' does not contain a definition for 
'SimulateTextEntry' Blah.cs 33  32  ALibrary
```

I do have `using WindowsInput` as a directive.

Does anyone know why the methods are not accessible?  Methods like `SimulateKeyPress()` are also not available.  These are the key API.  Am I missing something about adding this library and referencing it?

Comment: Hello! Really not sure, but check the target .Net version. I had a similar problem between a project targeting .Net 4.5 and library .net 4.5.1

Comment: how can i check the target .Net version?

Comment: Right click => properties. If you click on the reference it will not open external window, but just populate properties window. You’ll have a field “runtime version” for each reference

Comment: My runtime version is v2.0.50727

Comment: And what is the target version of your project?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So I just tried this lib.
Actually their documentation is just a little off. You need to create an instance of InputSimulator first, like this:

```
  InputSimulator s = new InputSimulator();
  s.Keyboard.TextEntry("Hello sim !");
```

Comment: is this any better than the native function,  SendKeys.Send("abc"); ?