# How to simulate keystroke in WPF, but outside the application?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-events

Currently I used this snip code as a result from googling.

> ```
> var eventArgs = new TextCompositionEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
>                 new TextComposition(InputManager.Current, Keyboard.FocusedElement, "A"));
> eventArgs.RoutedEvent = TextInputEvent;             
> var flag = InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(eventArgs);
> ```

It was working if I used Keyboard.Focus(TxtBox); and the TxtBox will be filled with the Keystroke.

But what I want really achieved is:

- 1.Drawing a box (for example, I draw box on one of the excel cell)
- 2.Click on the box coordinate (to change Keyboard Focus)
- 3.Send Keystroke to clicked excel cell

I have done step 1 and 2.
But I can't find a way to do the third step.

Somehow, the click event (using mouse event) maybe not changing Keyboard Focus automatically.

So, how do I change Keyboard focus, if possible using coordinate ?
Or maybe can I get IInputElement from a coordinate ? and then set keyboard focus to it.
Of course, all of it outside from the main application window of the WPF.

Comment: add the keystrokes to a different control that has focus at the time and just update the text of the target?

Comment: @mahlatse I dont think so. My target is outside of the wpf app window. In my example it is excel cell. How do I update the excel text then?

Comment: If it is an excel cell and you know the cell/grid, you can use a 3rd party library like EPPLUS to update the excel by loading it, just not sure you you would reload the excel file though.

Comment: @mahlatse Thank you for your idea. But excel here is just an example for simple explanation of what I tried to achieved. But it won't be an excel cell. It should be anythng that can be input-ed by text. Like notepad, search bar, etc.

Comment: If it is something that you created , then its simpler, if its something that you have no control over, you might need to do some magic dev[ assuming they allow command line parameters, etc]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it !

At:
[Installed InputSimulator via NuGet, no members accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987445/installed-inputsimulator-via-nuget-no-members-accessible)

It is working in most cases.

I said in most cases, because it is able to type in other window like excel application, but on other custom app window. There might be a case it won't work.

Hope it help for other people, looking for the same thing.