# How to make keybd_event hit tab three consecutive times

Tags: c#, winapi

I currently have this code

```
 keybd_event(0x09, 0, 0, 0);
 keybd_event(0x09, 0, 0, 0);
 keybd_event(0x09, 0, 0, 0);
```

to be able to hit tab three consecutive times, however, it only hits tab the first time and wont hit tab again.

When I try to debug it, whenever I continue to the second and third keybd_event, it shows the message "changes are not allowed while code is running"

Comment: The key goes down but does it come up again? Why are you calling a deprecated function. SendInput is your guy. From C# call SendKeys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending any `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` events in between each keystroke, eg:

```
keybd_event(0x09, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(0x09, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0, 0);
keybd_event(0x09, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(0x09, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0, 0);
keybd_event(0x09, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(0x09, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0, 0);
```

That being said, `keybd_event()` is decremented, you should be using [`SendInput()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) instead (see [Send keys through SendInput in user32.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761169/)), eg:

```
INPUT input = new INPUT {
    Type = 1
};
input.Data.Keyboard = new KEYBDINPUT() {
    Vk = 0x09,
    Scan = 0,
    Flags = 0,
    Time = 0,
    ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero,
};

INPUT input2 = new INPUT {
    Type = 1
};
input2.Data.Keyboard = new KEYBDINPUT() {
    Vk = 0x09,
    Scan = 0,
    Flags = 2,
    Time = 0,
    ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero
};

INPUT[] inputs = new INPUT[] { input, input2, input, input2, input, input2 };
SendInput(6, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
```

Or, you can use [`SendKeys()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) instead, eg:

```
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, feels so dumb now to not realize the keyup.

Comment: It's really bad to encourage keybd_event, deprecated as it is. Why can't you recommend SendInput.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Um, I did.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps I am drunk. Sorry. Still I'd encourage never ever including keybd_event. You know that the asker is going to use that code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can you explain why keybd_event is bad

Comment: I could. But I don't think I could do so better than the documentation already does.

Comment: @TonyZeyorkLin: The main reason is that `keybd_event()` suffers from a race condition that can cause corrupted input. Each call to `keybd_event()` is injected into the input queue as a separate event, with no safeguards to prevent other input events from being injected at the same time, either from the user or from other apps. That can cause multiple inputs to intermix events with each other in unpredictable ways. `SendInput()` was designed to eliminate that race condition by allowing multiple input events to be injected atomically at one time so they cannot be interrupted by other events.